# Unable to tweet using Twitter-OAuth in android

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, tweets

Iam using jtwitter library to authorize my app with Twitter. I used this http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/312.html to authenticate, tweet and read the status.. Authentication and reading status works fine. But on click of Tweet button getting the following exception. Where is the wrong ?? Please help me.

```
/* Responsible for posting new status to Twitter */
class PostStatusTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
  try {
    twitter.setStatus(params[0]);
    return "Successfully posted: " + params[0];
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
    return "Error connecting to server.";
  }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  super.onPostExecute(result);
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

 }
```

LOGACT:

```
W/System.err(3073): http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json (anonymous)
W/System.err(3073):     at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.processError(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:176)
W/System.err(3073):     at winterwell.jtwitter.OAuthSignpostClient.post(OAuthSignpostClient.java:129)
W/System.err(3073):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:3220)
W/System.err(3073):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:3161)
W/System.err(3073):     at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.setStatus(Twitter.java:2917)
W/System.err(3073):     at com.tarams.twitterdemo.MainActivity$PostStatusTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:244)
W/System.err(3073):     at com.tarams.twitterdemo.MainActivity$PostStatusTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
W/System.err(3073):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
W/System.err(3073):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
W/System.err(3073):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
W/System.err(3073):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
W/System.err(3073):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
W/System.err(3073):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS 
http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application#josc329